# Stripe::InvalidRequestError: This customer has no attached payment source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying to do the test signup at the end of lecture 113 in Upskill's Essential Web Developer course, however I get the following error and I have been over and over the previous lectures and cannot pinpoint where I have gone wrong.

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Users::RegistrationsController#create

This customer has no attached payment source

Extracted source (around line #10):

8  def save_with_subscription
9    if valid?
10      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
11      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
12      save!
13    end

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:10:in `save_with_subscription'
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `block in create'
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"/4EiUCLerdc0o+vIbZWWZzxC3cm1TSjyWGs/lYq/H4RiT6zwohUJUQnZaIrxADF2RiWcs6G3BDXiRDQT/bEa4Q==",
"plan"=>"2",
"user"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
"commit"=>"Sign up"}

Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

LOG

```
Started POST "/users" for 81.140.28.63 at 2017-01-18 21:24:44 +0000
Cannot render console from 81.140.28.63! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
    Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GIGatf9j6proPQgjnjCwR6r6BBeDLCYa2lhOG453bQLwln1wTOEbVSPaPow6ZLGBcGpvX3Qm1Fw03vpQc0Xtsg==", "plan"=>"2", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Plan Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 905ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)



Stripe::InvalidRequestError (This customer has no attached payment source):

app/models/user.rb:10:in `save_with_subscription'
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `block in create'
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `create'
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (9.5ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (43.3ms)
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're not actually passing the stripe_card_token as a parameter to the function. Take a look at your Parameters at the bottom and you've passed the plan, user data and commit info but no "card". Start there possibly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many thanks for taking the time to reply. So I gave it a few days and looked at it again last night and it turned out to be a rather simple and stupid mistake on my part.

In the lesson video and notes the instructor corrects a typo in the users.js file where he referenced an incorrect ID for the submit button in the form. He had typed

```
var submitBtn = $('#form-submit-btn');
```

but he had used the following in the form

```
var submitBtn = $('#form-signup-btn');
```

While I changed my users.js file to match the correction, somehow I had actually used #form-submit-btn' so when I corrected the users.js file per the lesson I actually caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend dividing out the requests to see which part of it is actually failing.  I *suspect* that the reason it's barfing is just because something else is happening and it's unable to manifest a meaningful error message.

Try this:

```
cus = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email)
self.stripe_customer_token = cus.id
cus.sources.create(source: stripe_card_token)
sub = Stripe::Subscription.create(customer: cus.id, plan: plan_id)
save!
```

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same issue.
I made the fix for the typo but still got the same error. It looks like the test card number used in the course video maybe another source for this
error too. I used a test number from the following page and all worked as expected.

https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards

Just my 2cents!